# automated folder structure creation with conditions

Tags: powershell, simplify

any idea / suggestion how to simplify this code? I would like to find different approach to create folders as they need to be created.

```
function TargetDir { # create folder structure for patches by OS type
  if ($col6 -like "*WindowsXP*" -or $col4 -like "*Windows XP*"
   ) {$TargetDir = "$Path\$col1\XP"
   if (!(Test-Path -path $TargetDir
   )) {New-Item $Path\$col1\XP -type directory
    New-Item -type file -Name $Col6 -Path $TargetDir}
   else {New-Item -type file -Name $Col6 -Path $TargetDir}
   }

  elseif ($col6 -like "*Windows6.0*" -or $col4 -like "*Vista*"
   ) {$TargetDir = "$Path\$col1\Vista"
   if (!(Test-Path -path $TargetDir
   ) ) {New-Item $Path\$col1\Vista -type directory
    New-Item -type file -Name $Col6 -Path $TargetDir}
    else {New-Item -type file -Name $Col6 -Path $TargetDir}
    }

   elseif ($col6 -like "*Windows6.1*" -or $col4 -like "*Windows 7*"
   ) {$TargetDir = "$Path\$col1\Win7"
    if (!(Test-Path -path $TargetDir
   ) ) {New-Item $Path\$col1\Win7 -type directory
   New-Item -type file -Name $Col6 -Path $TargetDir}
   else {New-Item -type file -Name $Col6 -Path $TargetDir}
   } 

  elseif ($col6 -like "*Windows8-RT*" -or $col4 -like "*Windows 8 *"
   ) {$TargetDir = "$Path\$col1\Win8"
   if (!(Test-Path -path $TargetDir)
   ) {New-Item $Path\$col1\Win8 -type directory
   New-Item -type file -Name $Col6 -Path $TargetDir}
    else {New-Item -type file -Name $Col6 -Path $TargetDir}
   } 

   elseif ($col6 -like "*Windows8.1*" -or $col4 -like "*Windows 8.1*"
   ) {$TargetDir = "$Path\$col1\Win81"
    if (! (Test-Path -path $TargetDir)
    ) {New-Item $Path\$col1\Win81 -type directory
    New-Item -type file -Name $Col6 -Path $TargetDir}
    else {New-Item -type file -Name $Col6 -Path $TargetDir}
   } 
  } # end if
```

Thank you for any suggestion how this could be simplified.

Comment: For starters I would use a switch statement. `$col#`  is not defined in this function either so this should not work as is

Comment: it is working, trust me. $col is defined elsewhere. I`ll try the switch.

Comment: Ok... if it is working then the scope is odd but a good practice is to use local scope whenever possible. There is no reason for you to no pass a few variables to the function which makes it make sense and more portable if you use it somewhere else. I don't see where a lot of these variables are populated like `$TargetDir` and `$Path`. A bunch should be $null looking at this. If you close and reopen powershell it still works?

Comment: I recant what i said about `$TargetDir` it was more `$path`

Comment: yes it works that way as well. What I posted here is only one function from script holding lot of code and 9 functions

Comment: Matt, don`t know where to mar your replay as answer but TY anyway for right tip! (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt thank you for your replay. I admit that I shared almost non detail but I had on my mind something much more simpler... Your suggestion to use switch was the key to get it done that way.

```
switch -wildcard ($FileName) 
{ 
    "*6.0*" { $TargetDir = "$Path\Vista\" } 
    "*6.1*" { $TargetDir = "$Path\Windows 7\" }  
    "*8-R*" { $TargetDir = "$Path\Windows 8\" } 
    "*8.1*" { $TargetDir = "$Path\Windows 8.1\" } 
    default { write-host "Define target directory for $FileName" -foreground "red"}
}
if (Test-Path -path $TargetDir) { 
    New-Item $TargetDir -type directory
    New-Item -type file -Name $FileName -Path $TargetDir
} else { 
    New-Item -type file -Name $FileName -Path $TargetDir -Force 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you find yourself using `elseif` a lot [switch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx) might be there to save you.

You are checking if `$col4` or `$col6` has a match correct? Since that appears the case you only really need to check one of those values as long as it is not blank (Just bear with me). Also to make your function more portable (if not for you then for others) then we are going to use function parameters.

```powershell
function Get-TargetDirectory{
    param(
        [string]$value1,
        [string]$value2,
        [string]$path,
        [string]$directory
    )

    If($value1){$toMatch = $value1} #The value of $value1 is tested to contain a non empty string / null
    If($value2){$toMatch = $value2} #The value of $value2 is tested to contain a non empty string / null

    switch -Regex ($toMatch){
        "Windows ?XP"{$TargetDir = "$Path\$directory\XP"}
        "(Windows6\.0|Vista)"{$TargetDir =  "$Path\$directory\Vista"}
        "(Windows6\.1|Windows 7)"{$TargetDir =  "$Path\$directory\Win7"}
        "Windows ?8"{$TargetDir =  "$Path\$directory\Win8"}
        "Windows ?8\.1"{$TargetDir =  "$Path\$directory\Win81"}
        default{$TargetDir = ""}
    }

    If($TargetDir){ #The value of $TargetDir is tested to contain a non empty string / null
        # Create the directory if it does not already exist
        If(!(Test-Path -path $TargetDir)){[void](New-Item $TargetDir -type Directory)}
        # Create the empty file in $TargetDir
        New-Item -type file -Name $value1 -Path $TargetDir    
    }
}
```

I changed the names in my function to be more friendly. The following is how they map to your previous names.

```
Yours   Get-TargetDirectory
$col1   $directory
$col4   $value2
$col6   $value1
$path   $path
```

Not perfect as there are some caveats that you dont already account for like the presence of the folder I refer to as `$directory`. Using the `-Regex` keyword we can simplify the match operations. Also, there is no need to have the code to create items exist multiple times since it will be called regardless.

Hopefully this, untested code, works for you and shows you some good coding practices.